# How to set complicated variable products with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am trying to make an e-commerce website with WooCommerce and Wordpress that is similar to the website [Print Home](https://printhome.co.uk). Where they have products like this: https://printhome.co.uk/products/standard-business-cards/
https://printhome.co.uk/materials/wallpaper/

As far as I have seen in WooCommerce for the variable product I only have attributes with fixed values. Afterwards for each combination I have to manually state the price. Is it possible to have a base value and based on the value chosen in attributes update the price?

Also how can I have attributes like width and height that user states and based on that price changes ? Based on width and height the delivery channel will also vary.

I am sorry for multiple questions in one, however I believe they are related and will be grateful for some guidelines. I am a novice in Wordpress so still not aware of many tools, so if there are other plugins or ways that will allow me to create this, please refer me those.

Thank You

Comment: i would look at commercial plugins on codecanyon.net. there is something for (almost) every need.  the first here might already be what you lookin' for: https://codecanyon.net/search/woocommerce%20price%20calculation  WooCommerce Measurement Price Calculator Plugin

Comment: @Beatroot I see there is a measurement price calculator which will allow me to help create the materials products. however, I cant seem to find any that will also vary the shipping charge

Comment: seems you need an additional plugin for that https://www.pluginhive.com/knowledge-base/easily-ship-products-custom-quantities-table-rate-shipping-pro-woocommerce-measurement-price-calculator-plugin/
you might wanna ask the respective supports to figure out if the two fit together. altough on the table rate plugin seems to be a full 30-day money back warranty.
look for "table rate" for shipping calculator. here are also some offers: https://codecanyon.net/search/woocommerce%20table%20rate